# Customized UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar

*DISCLAIMER:* I'm likely the wrong person to ask this, as I am only a designer in this scenario and know precisely jack about iOS development.

*DISCLAIMER OF DISCLAIMER:* I am however a proficient PHP and JS programmer, so the art/sense of development is not completely lost on me.

Now, the design we're trying to reproduce calls for a header bar. Currently it's a UINavigationBar. However, that element apparently doesn't allow for sufficient customization.

- The bar should have a height of 110 pixels (Retina).
- It should not have a gloss, a border or a visible background; the entire screen should have the same static unmoving background (image).
- The bar should only have a drop shadow (which is also an image, any internal drop shadow effect will not suffice) when the content below it has been scrolled. In other words, the drop shadow image is an indicator that "some content is up here". If I remember correctly from my Galaxy days, such behavior is familiar to Android users.

I've attached a part of the design mockup here;

[image: Design mockup showcasing the bar behavior]

What is the path of least resistance to achieve this effect (with the native UINavigationBar if possible, but no sweat if not)?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this would be adding a class which inherits `UINavigationBar` and implement the `drawRect` method to draw the navigation bar  image with shadow  in the context.

```
@interface MynavBar:UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation MynavBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
 UIImage *navBarImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"];
[navBarImg drawRect:rect];
[super drawRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Use this class as the class name for your navigation bar in the IB.

Comment: As far as I can understand this, it looks like it will place an image for the header bar; Would this approach work with the ideal that the background of the app (the blue diagonal stripes) should not scroll when the content is scrolled?

Comment: This will work!, it works well in my apps where i use custom navigationbars. Its a fixed image drawn in that `view` hence it will not move @emphram stvanger.

Comment: @kaar3k Is this going to work if `navBar.png` has a height of 110 px ?

Comment: It will because drawrect has a parameter called  `rect` which specifies the rectangle in which your image has to be scaled.

Comment: @kaar3k I understood that, but as you can see from the mockup, the background is continuous with the content area (i.e. when there's no shadow, you can't tell where the header ends and the content begins). When the user scrolls, I don't want the background of the content area to move, and break the continuity of the pattern. Is that still achievable with your method?

Comment: Furthermore, this answer only addresses the height problem. I still need a solution for the drop shadow behavior. :)

Comment: If your image contains shadow that will have same effect in the UINavBar .Try once in your code

Answer (score 0):

Well,in your case, i think it's not possible to use `UINavigationBar`. Because, default `navigationBar` height is read-only so, you cannot change it programmatically. Once, i tried to make bigger navigation bar, but it doesn't really work, because you cannot control default back button location if you need it. If you don't need to navigation bar, i think you should use a custom view with background image, so you can set its frame whatever you want.